# When to use call or what is the benefit to use call in Javscript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, prototype, ramda.js

I am going through the source code of Ramda.JS which is a functional library for Javascript developers. These a few lines of codes confused me a bit.

```
var sort = _curry2(function sort(comparator, list) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(list, 0).sort(comparator);
});
```

My question is that

- `Array.prototype.slice.call(list, 0)` should be exactly same to `list.slice(0)`, but the second way is much shorter
- Why use `.call` here, why not use the second way?

  - Is there any benefits to use call here?

### References

- [Sort Function of ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/1e0e5006129f0369700308135f9f0a28fae617ed/source/sort.js#L26)
- [JS call function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

---

### an update

A great thanks to [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz).

this screenshot is from what he suggested in his/her comment.

[image]

`a.slice(0)` and `Array.prototype.slice.call(a, 0)` are very different on non-array object.

Comment: I tried google, but non results can help on this question

Comment: Did you mean to ask why aren't they using `list.slice(0)` instead (not: `list.slice()[0]`)

Comment: Try calling this with `list = {0: "foo", 1: "bar", 2: "baz", length: 3}` and try the same with your suggested implementation. If you think that example is contrived, then try it with `document.querySelectorAll("div")`

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for your comment, this answered my question

Comment: Another way of putting this is that the implementation used here works for arrays, but also for value that are enough like arrays, things with `length` property and low-integer-keyed properties.  As well as the arbitrary objects and NodeLists described, this also includes `arguments` objects and Strings.  Ramda was started before ES5 was ubiquitous.  When Ramda is rewritten in modern JS, it might skip this and use a syntax like `[...val]` or `Array.from(val)`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Are there plans for rewriting Ramda in ES6? Or is that more for the indeterminate future? I'd be very interested to see what it would look like with more modern syntax.

Comment: @VLAZ: No one has been spending the time to wrap things up for a good version 1.0.  But once we do that, the plan is to move to ES6, which should simplify much of the implementation.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you. I really like Ramda and I'm looking forward to more of it. I'll probably start tracking the development more closely as I'm curious how that would go. I think you're all doing an awesome job, so thanks for your work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth noting that using `Array.prototype.slice.call(arr, 0)` over `arr.slice()` doesn't throw an error when `arr` isn't an array/string and `arr` doesn't have the `slice` method.

Perhaps they wanted a more robust implementation, thus using the first approach.

Comment: thanks.

`Array.prototype.slice.call(undefined, 0)` but it likes that this will throw the error too

Answer (score 2):

From the signature I can say list.slice()[0] is totally different than Array.prototype.slice.call(list, 0), in the former statement you first call list.slice and access it's 0th index element, in later statement you are calling Array.slice passing context as the value of list and 0 as an argument to the slice function.

Comment: thanks, this is my mistake, I just update the question.

Comment: I do mean `Array.prototype.slice.call(divs, 0)` vs `divs.slice(0)`

Answer (score 2):

From my view, `Array.prototype.slice.call` supports Array-Like Objects, such as NodeList collection.

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
divs.slice(0)
//Uncaught TypeError: divs.slice is not a function
Array.prototype.slice.call(divs, 0)
//(222) [div.ng-toast.ng-toast--right.ng-toast--bottom.ng-toast--animate-fade, ……
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted, this makes sense, just curious whether there is any other reasons?

Comment: slice method can also be called to convert Array-like objects/collections to a new Array. You just bind the method to the object. The arguments inside a function is an example of an 'array-like object'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects